# How to import Wagtail ModelAdmin index page into a template

Tags: django, wagtail, modeladmin

I created a new AdminModel as follows:

```py
class OneModelAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    model = SomeModel
    menu_label = 'One'
    edit_view_class = OneEditView
    edit_template_name = '.../one-edit.html'
    index_view_class = OneIndexView
    index_template_name = '...'

class TwoModelAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    model = SomeOtherModel
    menu_label = 'Two'
    edit_view_class = TwoEditView
    edit_template_name = '.../two-edit.html'
    index_view_class = TwoIndexView
    index_template_name = '...'
```

How can I import the TwoModelAdmin index view inside the OneModelAdmin edit template?

## Edit:

```py
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import IndexView

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 50
    index_view_class = IndexView
    edit_view_class = MyEditView
    create_view_class = MyCreateView
    button_helper_class = MyButtonHelper
    allowed_lookup = []
```

Comment: Django and Wagtail each have classes named ModelAdmin. If you really have a MyModelAdmin class, can you please show the code for that? If not, could you please show the import statements for the class you are inheriting from?

Comment: Thanks @cnk, the code is updated